# Plotly dash refreshing global data on reload

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

Imagine I have a `dash` application where I want the global data to refresh on page reload. I'm using a function to serve the layout as described [here](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates). However, I'm note sure how/where I should define `df` such that I can use it in callbacks (like in a case where I'd like to subset the `df` based on some input and pass it to a layout table). My code below reloads the data on page refresh, but the callback cannot access the `df`.

I'm very new to `dash` so apologies in advance for potentially dumb question.

```
def serve_layout():
    df = # Fetch data from DB
    
    return # Layout

app.layout = serve_layout

@app.callback()
def my_func:
    # Here I want to reference df
```

Comment: Is the DB query expensive (i.e. does it take a long time)? Do you have multiple callbacks referencing the data frame or just one?

Comment: The query is potentially expensive, and there will be multiple callbacks referencing the data. Basically I wan to be able to re-provide the global dataset on demand. But once the data is loaded, everything in the app will be based on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common approach for sharing data between callbacks is to save the data in a `dash_core_components.Store` object,

```
def serve_layout():
    df = # Fetch data from DB
    store = Store(id="mystore", data=df.to_json())  # The store must be added to the layout
    return # Layout
```

You can then add the store as a `State` argument for the callbacks that need access to the data,

```
@app.callback(..., [State("mystore", "data")])
def my_func(..., data):
    df = pd.read_json(data)
```

The main drawback of this approach is that the data is exchanged between the client and the server *each time a callback is invoked*. If the data frame is small, it doesn't really matter, but if it is large, the data exchange (and the serialization to/from JSON) might cause severe performance issues. It can be avoided by caching the data frame server side, either manually as demonstrated in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks) or using the enriched components from `dash-extensions`. Here is a small example of the latter,

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from dash_extensions.enrich import Dash, ServersideOutput, Output, Input, Trigger

app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Store(id="store"),  # this is the store that holds the data
                       html.Div(id="onload"),  # this div is used to trigger the query_df function on page load
                       html.Div(id="log")])


@app.callback(ServersideOutput("store", "data"), Trigger("onload", "children"))
def query_df():
    return pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(int(10)), columns=["rnd"])  # some random example data


@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), Input("store", "data"))
def print_df(df):
    return df.to_json()  # do something with the data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

tested with `dash-extensions==0.0.27rc1`. Disclaimer: I am the author of `dash-extensions`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the dataframe is large, is it better to go with server side caching or storing the data in the browser in a hidden div?

Comment: Storing the data in a hidden div will yield similar performance as using a Store object. If your data frame is large, server side caching is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe a bit off track here but the documentation you linked to mentions "Note that filesystem cache doesn't work on systems with ephemeral filesystems like Heroku.". Do you know if this would work on GCP App Engine?

Comment: I haven't worked with GCP App Engine in a long time, but typically you will need to use another type of storage than the file system when you deploy to scalable, stateless cloud environments. It's a bit off topic though (and not specific to Dash), so i think that the discussion should be continued in another question.